# How to make javaScript Events to execute in a order / Sequence

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using prototype.js .

This is my code:

```
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() {
    new Ajax.Request('/HumblFin/Serv',
        {
         method:'get',
         onSuccess: function(transport){

    var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

        drawChart(data);
           },
         onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
        });
function drawChart(data)
{
     for (var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++)  { 
         priceData.push([i, data.jobs[i].INCPU]);
         dateData.push(data.jobs[i].Dater);
        }

}

HumbleFinance.init('finance', priceData , dateData);
```

`HumbleFinance.init('finance', priceData , dateData);`  is responsible to display the charts .

The question is, the HumbleFinance.init is being called earlier than the AJAX call, so its displaying empty chart .

Please tell me how can I supply the returned data from Ajax call to the function  `HumbleFinance.init('finance', priceData , dateData);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what `data` is and how it relates to `HumbleFinance.init`, but just put the function call in the callback:

```
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() {
    new Ajax.Request('/HumblFin/Serv', {
         method:'get',
         onSuccess: function(transport){
            var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
            HumbleFinance.init('finance', priceData , dateData);
            drawChart(data);
         },
         onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that prototype automatically evaluates JSON if the `Content-type` of the request is set to `application/json`.

You can access it as `var data = transport.responseJSON;`